# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(|3x+4y|+|4y-3x|)}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(|3x+4y|+|4y-3x|)}dxdy$
I set $3x+4y=u,4y-3x=v$ and then $|J|=\frac{1}{25}$.
Taking exhaustion of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be $A_n=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-n\leq u\leq n,-n \leq v \leq n\}$
$\int_{-n}^{n}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{-|u|+|v|}dudv$ and here i got stuck on how to calculate it.
My intuition is that I can somehow show that it is enough to calculate on 1 quarter but now sure how to justify it

Comment: Your intuition is correct, because it is even function for both variables.

Comment: @zkutch It is not an even function of both variables. If you keep $y$ fixed, it is not an even function of $x$, for example.

Comment: @uniquesolution. I am speaking about last integral and variables $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @zkutch can you explain how it's an even function?

Comment: @ron kurman . There are $|u|$ and $|v|$. You see mistake somewhere?

Comment: @ron kurman The integrand is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Along the line $y=-x$, for example, it is exponentially large. Can you prove it is integrable at all?

Comment: @zkutch Didn't understand your question

Comment: @uniquesolution So you say it doesn't converge :( how do you prove this?

Comment: @ron kurman . I mean absolute value is even - do you agree? And uniquesolution seems is right: $\int_{0}^{n}e^udu$ is divergent.

Comment: I think i wrote the question wrong and even when i tried to solve this, i'm fixing this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral does not converge, as is shown by your own calculation after making the change of variables. As zkutch pointed out, you have there an integral of a positive function, of the form $\int_0^n e^{|u|}$, so in the region $|u|>|v|$, which obviously has positive measure, the integral will diverge.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think i made the mistake when writing the integral wrong ... but Thanks for answering and explain.even from mistakes you learn something :)